# PyODBC Connection Issue on Apache 2.4

Tags: python, sql-server, apache, github, web

I was running my application under Apache 2.4 and mod_wsgi. 
The ODBC connection works fine using Python Shell and 500 Internal Server Error when working under Apache HTTP Server.

But whenever try to load the module from **httpd.config** by adding

```
 LoadModule pyodbc_module
 "c:/users/desktop/appdata/local/programs/python/python36-32/lib/site-packages/pyodbc.cp36-win32.pyd"
```

and restarting the server results in **httpd -k restart**

```
httpd: Syntax error on line 576 of C:/Apache24/conf/httpd.conf: Can't locate API module structure `pyodbc_module' in file C:/Users/Vitriv-Desktop/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36-32/Lib/site-packages/pyodbc.cp36-win32.pyd: No error
```

#### error.log

> ```
> [cgi:error] [pid 9344:tid 1264] [client ::1:52332] AH01215:
>
> End of script output before headers: hello_get.py, referer: http://localhost/index.html
> Traceback (most recent call last):\r: C:/Apache24/htdocs/hello_get.py, referer: http://localhost/index.html
> File "C:\\Apache24\\htdocs\\hello_get.py", line 6, in <module>\r: C:/Apache24/htdocs/hello_get.py, referer: http://localhost/index.html
> import pyodbc\r: C:/Apache24/htdocs/hello_get.py, referer: http://localhost/index.html
> ImportError: No module named pyodbc\r: C:/Apache24/htdocs/hello_get.py, referer: http://localhost/index.html
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Apache ***500 Internal Error Solved***. Because of ***importing pypyodbc instead of pyodbc***.
In python shell I was able to connect successfully retrive the results in **python shell** as well as **MSSQL Server 2017**.

---